# Mongoid Paperclip Transcoder Issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip

I have successfully been using the Mongoid-Paperclip gem to upload and resize photos, but now that I need to do the same with videos, needing to encode them in various formats, I did a bit of googling and came across the [Paperclip Transcoder](https://github.com/ruby-av/paperclip-av-transcoder) gem that seems to do what I need.

That being said, after installing the gem and setting up my video model, I get the following error when running my unit tests: `LoadError: Could not find the 'Transcoder' processor in any of these paths: lib/paperclip, lib/paperclip_processors`

This tells me that the transcoder processor can't be located even though it is installed, which makes me wonder if this gem will work with the mongoid-paperclip.
Is anybody using this two gems together? Am I missing some configuration?

I don't mind having to write my own paperclip processor to encode the videos but I'd rather avoid reinventing the wheel if possible.

Additional notes: Ruby on Rails 4, Mongoid 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after a few tries I figured that adding `require "paperclip/av/transcoder"` to the `/lib/myengine.rb` file did the trick.